# How to get the right type of bandgap(indirect/direct) in VASP?

Tags: vasp, electronic-structure, bandgap

I am trying to calculate the band gap type(Direct or Indirect) of TiO2-Rutile, according to the [Material Project](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-2657/#electronic-structure), rutile is a direct bandgap type semiconductor. The VBM and CBM are both at the Gamma point.
I try to use VASP to calculate the electronic structure of a TiO2-Rutile unit cell. But my result shows that it is an indirect bandgap material. As shown below, there is a small energy difference of two valence bands at Gamma and M points.
My question is:
If my calculation is wrong, how should I improve my calculation settings? I have already tried to increase the number of k-points, set `PREC = Accurate`, but still got the same result.

[image]

I follow the standard procedure:

1. Structure optimization
2. Self-consistent field calculation
3. Band structure calculation

Here are the input files used for 1st step:

INCAR:

```
DFT+U Calculation
LDAU   = .TRUE.        (Activate DFT+U)
LDATYPE=  2            (Dudarev; only U-J matters)
LDAUL  =  2 -1         (Orbitals for each species)
LDAUU  =  4.5  0         (U for each species)
LDAUJ  =  0  0         (J for each species)
LMAXMIX=  4            (Mixing cut-off; 4-d, 6-f)
 
Global Parameters
ISTART =  1            (Read existing wavefunction; if there)
ISPIN  =  2            (Non-Spin polarised DFT)
# ICHARG =  11         (Non-self-consistent: GGA/LDA band structures)
LREAL  = .FALSE.       (Projection operators: automatic)
ENCUT  =  520        (Cut-off energy for plane wave basis set, in eV)
PREC   =  Accurate       (Precision level)
LWAVE  = .TRUE.        (Write WAVECAR or not)
LCHARG = .TRUE.        (Write CHGCAR or not)
ADDGRID= .TRUE.        (Increase grid; helps GGA convergence)
# LVTOT  = .TRUE.      (Write total electrostatic potential into LOCPOT or not)
# LVHAR  = .TRUE.      (Write ionic + Hartree electrostatic potential into LOCPOT or not)
# NELECT =             (No. of electrons: charged cells; be careful)
# LPLANE = .TRUE.      (Real space distribution; supercells)
# NPAR   = 4           (Max is no. nodes; don't set for hybrids)
# Nwrite = 2           (Medium-level output)
# KPAR   = 2           (Divides k-grid into separate groups)
# NGX    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
# NGY    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
# NGZ    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
 
Electronic Relaxation
ISMEAR =  0            (Gaussian smearing; metals:1)
SIGMA  =  0.05         (Smearing value in eV; metals:0.2)
NELM   =  90           (Max electronic SCF steps)
NELMIN =  6            (Min electronic SCF steps)
EDIFF  =  1E-08        (SCF energy convergence; in eV)
# GGA  =  PS           (PBEsol exchange-correlation)
 
Ionic Relaxation
NSW    =  100          (Max ionic steps)
IBRION =  2            (Algorithm: 0-MD; 1-Quasi-New; 2-CG)
ISIF   =  2            (Stress/relaxation: 2-Ions, 3-Shape/Ions/V, 4-Shape/Ions)
EDIFFG = -2E-03        (Ionic convergence; eV/AA)
# ISYM =  2            (Symmetry: 0=none; 2=GGA; 3=hybrids)
```

KPOINTS:

```
K-Spacing Value to Generate K-Mesh: 0.040
0
Gamma
   5   5   8
0.0  0.0  0.0
```

POSCAR:

```
Ti2 O4
1.0
        4.6532721519         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         4.6532721519         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000         2.9692029953
   Ti    O
    2    4
Cartesian
     2.326636076         2.326636076         1.484601498
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
     0.909342430         3.743929583         1.484601498
     3.743929583         0.909342430         1.484601498
     1.417293646         1.417293646         0.000000000
     3.235978645         3.235978645         0.000000000
```

Here are the input files used for 2nd step:

INCAR:

```
DFT+U Calculation
LDAU   = .TRUE.        (Activate DFT+U)
LDATYPE=  2            (Dudarev; only U-J matters)
LDAUL  =  2 -1         (Orbitals for each species)
LDAUU  =  4.5  0         (U for each species)
LDAUJ  =  0  0         (J for each species)
LMAXMIX=  4            (Mixing cut-off; 4-d, 6-f)
 
Global Parameters
ISTART =  1            (Read existing wavefunction; if there)
ISPIN  =  2            (Non-Spin polarised DFT)
# ICHARG =  11         (Non-self-consistent: GGA/LDA band structures)
LREAL  = .FALSE.       (Projection operators: automatic)
ENCUT  =  520        (Cut-off energy for plane wave basis set, in eV)
PREC   =  Accurate       (Precision level)
LWAVE  = .TRUE.        (Write WAVECAR or not)
LCHARG = .TRUE.        (Write CHGCAR or not)
ADDGRID= .TRUE.        (Increase grid; helps GGA convergence)
# LVTOT  = .TRUE.      (Write total electrostatic potential into LOCPOT or not)
# LVHAR  = .TRUE.      (Write ionic + Hartree electrostatic potential into LOCPOT or not)
# NELECT =             (No. of electrons: charged cells; be careful)
# LPLANE = .TRUE.      (Real space distribution; supercells)
# NPAR   = 4           (Max is no. nodes; don't set for hybrids)
# Nwrite = 2           (Medium-level output)
# KPAR   = 2           (Divides k-grid into separate groups)
# NGX    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
# NGY    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
# NGZ    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
 
Electronic Relaxation
ISMEAR =  0            (Gaussian smearing; metals:1)
SIGMA  =  0.05         (Smearing value in eV; metals:0.2)
NELM   =  90           (Max electronic SCF steps)
NELMIN =  6            (Min electronic SCF steps)
EDIFF  =  1E-08        (SCF energy convergence; in eV)
LORBIT =  11
# GGA  =  PS           (PBEsol exchange-correlation)
 
Ionic Relaxation
#NSW    =  100          (Max ionic steps)
#IBRION =  2            (Algorithm: 0-MD; 1-Quasi-New; 2-CG)
#ISIF   =  2            (Stress/relaxation: 2-Ions, 3-Shape/Ions/V, 4-Shape/Ions)
EDIFFG = -2E-03        (Ionic convergence; eV/AA)
# ISYM =  2            (Symmetry: 0=none; 2=GGA; 3=hybrids)
```

KPOINTS:

```
K-Spacing Value to Generate K-Mesh: 0.020
0
Gamma
  11  11  17
0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Here are the input files used for 3rd step:

INCAR:

```
DFT+U Calculation
LDAU   = .TRUE.        (Activate DFT+U)
LDATYPE=  2            (Dudarev; only U-J matters)
LDAUL  =  2 -1         (Orbitals for each species)
LDAUU  =  4.5  0         (U for each species)
LDAUJ  =  0  0         (J for each species)
LMAXMIX=  4            (Mixing cut-off; 4-d, 6-f)
 
Global Parameters
ISTART =  1            (Read existing wavefunction; if there)
ISPIN  =  2            (Non-Spin polarised DFT)
ICHARG =  11         (Non-self-consistent: GGA/LDA band structures)
LREAL  = .FALSE.       (Projection operators: automatic)
ENCUT  =  520        (Cut-off energy for plane wave basis set, in eV)
PREC   =  Accurate       (Precision level)
LWAVE  = .TRUE.        (Write WAVECAR or not)
LCHARG = .TRUE.        (Write CHGCAR or not)
ADDGRID= .TRUE.        (Increase grid; helps GGA convergence)
# LVTOT  = .TRUE.      (Write total electrostatic potential into LOCPOT or not)
# LVHAR  = .TRUE.      (Write ionic + Hartree electrostatic potential into LOCPOT or not)
# NELECT =             (No. of electrons: charged cells; be careful)
# LPLANE = .TRUE.      (Real space distribution; supercells)
# NPAR   = 4           (Max is no. nodes; don't set for hybrids)
# Nwrite = 2           (Medium-level output)
# KPAR   = 2           (Divides k-grid into separate groups)
# NGX    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
# NGY    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
# NGZ    = 500         (FFT grid mesh density for nice charge/potential plots)
 
Electronic Relaxation
ISMEAR =  0            (Gaussian smearing; metals:1)
SIGMA  =  0.05         (Smearing value in eV; metals:0.2)
NELM   =  90           (Max electronic SCF steps)
NELMIN =  6            (Min electronic SCF steps)
EDIFF  =  1E-08        (SCF energy convergence; in eV)
LORBIT =  11
# GGA  =  PS           (PBEsol exchange-correlation)
 
Ionic Relaxation
#NSW    =  100          (Max ionic steps)
#IBRION =  2            (Algorithm: 0-MD; 1-Quasi-New; 2-CG)
#ISIF   =  2            (Stress/relaxation: 2-Ions, 3-Shape/Ions/V, 4-Shape/Ions)
EDIFFG = -2E-03        (Ionic convergence; eV/AA)
# ISYM =  2            (Symmetry: 0=none; 2=GGA; 3=hybrids)
```

KPOINTS

```
K-Path Generated by VASPKIT.
   20
Line-Mode
Reciprocal
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000     GAMMA          
   0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000     X              
 
   0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000     X              
   0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000     M              
 
   0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000     M              
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000     GAMMA          
 
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000     GAMMA          
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000     Z              
 
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000     Z              
   0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000     R              
 
   0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000     R              
   0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000     A              
 
   0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000     A              
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000     Z              
 
   0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000     X              
   0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000     R              
 
   0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000     M              
   0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000     A
```

Comment: Have you tried running the Materials Project VASP input to check whether you reproduce their results then? https://materialsproject.org/tasks/mp-2657#mp-1440865

Comment: @PhilHasnip. I just test the setting from Material Project and the parameter difference. When I don't use DFT+U, the bandgap type is right.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer now Jack? Please update us!